# How not to share authentication cookie between different webapps with the same auth server

Tags: authentication, cookies

This question is the opposite that what most questions/tutorial are talking about.

Lets assume we have 2 SPA under the same domain. For example `spa1.company.com` and `spa2.company.com`. They are both authenticate against the same api `api.company.com`

The server set a cookie `httponly`, `secure`, `samesite=strict` with the domain `api.company.com`. The cookie is only needed by the authenticated function `api.company.com/authenticate` (so the path of the cookie is `/authenticate`)

(as far as I understand, it cannot be set as `spa1.company.com` becasue then it won't be sent when calling `api.copmany.com`)

So now the cookie will be sent by both SPA when they call to the authenticate method. What the settings should be in order to have 1 cookie per SPA?

I can do some funny stuff with the path to mitigate it, but I'm sure there are better solutions out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this solution with pinch of salt. It works well, but maybe there is a more best practice approach.

Add to the URL an app idnetifier for the clinet. For example:

1. `api.company.com/authenticate/spa1`
2. `api.company.com/authenticate/spa2`

Then you can set the path of the cookie to include the app identifier and it won't be shared between the clients